# python print current line number of running python file

Tags: python, line-numbers

is there any easy way to print current line number of running python file?

```py
a = 1
print(__line__)
b = 2
c = a+b
print(__line__)
```

Desired output:

```py
2
5
```

Comment: Yes, in interpretter it allways prints 1 right?

Comment: Yes, because it's basically always line 1 in an interactive session.